# Laravel sanctum too many tokens in database

Tags: laravel, token, bearer-token, laravel-sanctum, laravel-api

I am using Laravel Sanctum for creating API tokens.
But anyone can create limitless tokens via sending request to login route without an authorization header.

I can't delete existing tokens because maybe a user has 2 phones, and 2 laptops and logged in from each of them. 
I don't know how to create only one token for one device. Namely, deleting the exact token belong the device and create new one in case a user sends the request again to login route.

I tested sending a latest token of a user (if user have any tokens) instead of creating a new token on every request to login route but no luck because tokens are hashed in DB.

so, what is the best practise for solving too many tokens problem in database?

Here is login function

```
public function __invoke(Request $request)
{
    $validated = $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|string'
    ]);
    
    // find user
    $user = User::where('email', $validated['email'])->first();

    if (!$user || !Hash::check($validated['password'], $user->password)) {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => __('auth.failed')
        ], 200);
    }

    // store token
    $token = $user->createToken($user->name.'-token')->plainTextToken;

    return response()->json([
        'success' => true,
        'message' => 'Successfully logged in',
        'user' => $user,
        'token' => $token
    ], 200);
}
```

this is the db records of personal_access_tokens
[image]

Comment: Most services I am aware of do have a limit of how many concurrent devices you have have a time. It doesn't have to be too restrictive you can say "50 concurrent devices at a time" that should be enough for all your legitimate users. Then your approach after that could be either to trim down the tokens for a user when they try to generate a new one. (i.e. keep only latest 50)

Comment: @apokryfos for now I am going implement this

Comment: if there was a way to find out device we could easily name a token and every time new login request we can delete and create new token with name. there is User-Agent header but I don't know how much unique it is

Comment: I was suggesting using the created_at date (or updated_at date) and keep the latest ones. If you want you can also add a "last_activity" date in that table and update it each time a request using that token comes in and delete the least active tokens. You should not need to know the app a token is for. In the end of the day none of your legitimate users should ever face any issues with this. I would think only during a DDoS will you ever get users generating such a large volume of tokens.

Comment: As a small tweak to @apokryfos suggestion, you could implement a rate limit instead of an absolute limit. Only let users create X tokens in Y minutes/hours. It's probably not necessary, but it would allow you to support the rare user to might legitimately need more tokens than whatever your arbitrary limit would be.

Comment: Just to clarify, for me the only concern is a DDoS filling up your database and bringing your site down because the database can't connect anymore or having you incur crazy hosting costs due to high storage use. There's no real performance hit for your average user assuming you have an index on the `user_id` and `token` columns since the lookups even for huge tables will be fast when using the index so the limit of 50 I suggested is just a number that I think looks large enough that a regular user could never reach. You can adjust as needed for your own app